# Correct notation for probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a sequence of $n$ iid random variables (RV) $ X_1,X_2,...,X_n$
I want to denote the probability of **at least one** of those RV being lower than a threshold $x$.
Is this notation correct?

$P(X_1,X_2,...,X_n<x)$

Or does this mean probability of  **all** RV being lower than $x$?

Comment: I would write $P(\min\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}<x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n <x)$ means **all** RV being lesser than $x$.

The desired event for which you want to denote its probability sounds *ad hoc*, so I wouldn't expect it to be only one way of denoting it. One way (perhaps the most intuitive) is as callculus suggests:  $P(\min\{X_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq n\} <x)$. Another possibility is $P(\{i \mid X_i <x \} \neq \varnothing)$, or $P(\#\{i \mid X_i <x \} >0)$.